# HDF5 built with parallel support but mpi specific functions are not found

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, hdf5, trilinos

I am trying to compile from sources [trilinos](https://trilinos.github.io/), which depends on hdf5. As explained in [this guide](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_parallel), hdf5 can be configured with parallel support if necessary, and I did so by passing `HDF5_ENABLE_PARALLEL=ON` to cmake. I found [here](https://accserv.lepp.cornell.edu/svn/packages/hdf5/release_docs/INSTALL_CMake.txt) that some options are not compatible with parallel support (e.g. threadsafety), so I disabled them. 
Here is the output of cmake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Check for working C compiler: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpicc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpicc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpic++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpic++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- SOVERSION: 10.3.1
-- SOVERSION_TOOLS: 10.0.6
-- SOVERSION_CXX: 15.0.0
-- SOVERSION_F: 10.0.5
-- SOVERSION_HL: 10.2.1
-- SOVERSION_HL_CXX: 11.1.1
-- SOVERSION_HL_F: 10.0.4
-- Check for STD namespace
-- Check for STD namespace - found
-- Looking for ceil in m;
-- Looking for ceil in m; - found
-- Looking for dlopen in dl;m
-- Looking for dlopen in dl;m - found
-- Looking for WSAStartup in ws2_32;m;dl
-- Looking for WSAStartup in ws2_32;m;dl - not found
-- Looking for gethostbyname in wsock32;m;dl
-- Looking for gethostbyname in wsock32;m;dl - not found
-- Looking for gethostname in ucb;m;dl
-- Looking for gethostname in ucb;m;dl - not found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Other Test STDC_HEADERS - Success
-- Looking for include file sys/file.h
-- Looking for include file sys/file.h - found
-- Looking for include files sys/file.h, sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for include files sys/file.h, sys/ioctl.h - found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/resource.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/resource.h - found
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/socket.h
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/socket.h - found
-- Looking for 5 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/stat.h
-- Looking for 5 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/time.h
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for 7 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/types.h
-- Looking for 7 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for 8 include files sys/file.h, ..., features.h
-- Looking for 8 include files sys/file.h, ..., features.h - not found
-- Looking for 8 include files sys/file.h, ..., dirent.h
-- Looking for 8 include files sys/file.h, ..., dirent.h - found
-- Looking for 9 include files sys/file.h, ..., setjmp.h
-- Looking for 9 include files sys/file.h, ..., setjmp.h - found
-- Looking for 10 include files sys/file.h, ..., stddef.h
-- Looking for 10 include files sys/file.h, ..., stddef.h - found
-- Looking for 11 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdint.h
-- Looking for 11 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdint.h - found
-- Looking for 12 include files sys/file.h, ..., unistd.h
-- Looking for 12 include files sys/file.h, ..., unistd.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h - found
-- Looking for 13 include files sys/file.h, ..., mach/mach_time.h
-- Looking for 13 include files sys/file.h, ..., mach/mach_time.h - found
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., io.h
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., io.h - not found
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., winsock2.h
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., winsock2.h - not found
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/timeb.h
-- Looking for 14 include files sys/file.h, ..., sys/timeb.h - found
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., globus/common.h
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., globus/common.h - not found
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., pdb.h
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., pdb.h - not found
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., pthread.h
-- Looking for 15 include files sys/file.h, ..., pthread.h - found
-- Looking for 16 include files sys/file.h, ..., srbclient.h
-- Looking for 16 include files sys/file.h, ..., srbclient.h - not found
-- Looking for 16 include files sys/file.h, ..., string.h
-- Looking for 16 include files sys/file.h, ..., string.h - found
-- Looking for 17 include files sys/file.h, ..., strings.h
-- Looking for 17 include files sys/file.h, ..., strings.h - found
-- Looking for 18 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdlib.h
-- Looking for 18 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for 19 include files sys/file.h, ..., memory.h
-- Looking for 19 include files sys/file.h, ..., memory.h - found
-- Looking for 20 include files sys/file.h, ..., dlfcn.h
-- Looking for 20 include files sys/file.h, ..., dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for 21 include files sys/file.h, ..., inttypes.h
-- Looking for 21 include files sys/file.h, ..., inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for 22 include files sys/file.h, ..., netinet/in.h
-- Looking for 22 include files sys/file.h, ..., netinet/in.h - found
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_OFF64_T - Failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for ftello
-- Looking for ftello - found
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STAT64_STRUCT - Success
-- Looking for fstat64
-- Looking for fstat64 - found
-- Looking for stat64
-- Looking for stat64 - found
-- Check size of char
-- Check size of char - done
-- Check size of short
-- Check size of short - done
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of unsigned
-- Check size of unsigned - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of __int64
-- Check size of __int64 - failed
-- Check size of float
-- Check size of float - done
-- Check size of double
-- Check size of double - done
-- Check size of long double
-- Check size of long double - done
-- Check size of int8_t
-- Check size of int8_t - done
-- Check size of uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t - done
-- Check size of int_least8_t
-- Check size of int_least8_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least8_t
-- Check size of uint_least8_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast8_t
-- Check size of int_fast8_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast8_t
-- Check size of uint_fast8_t - done
-- Check size of int16_t
-- Check size of int16_t - done
-- Check size of uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t - done
-- Check size of int_least16_t
-- Check size of int_least16_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least16_t
-- Check size of uint_least16_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast16_t
-- Check size of int_fast16_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast16_t
-- Check size of uint_fast16_t - done
-- Check size of int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t - done
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Check size of int_least32_t
-- Check size of int_least32_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least32_t
-- Check size of uint_least32_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast32_t
-- Check size of int_fast32_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast32_t
-- Check size of uint_fast32_t - done
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
-- Check size of uint64_t
-- Check size of uint64_t - done
-- Check size of int_least64_t
-- Check size of int_least64_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least64_t
-- Check size of uint_least64_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast64_t
-- Check size of int_fast64_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast64_t
-- Check size of uint_fast64_t - done
-- Check size of off_t
-- Check size of off_t - done
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Looking for 23 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdbool.h
-- Looking for 23 include files sys/file.h, ..., stdbool.h - found
-- Check size of _Bool
-- Check size of _Bool - done
-- Performing Other Test DEV_T_IS_SCALAR - Success
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC - not found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_TM_GMTOFF - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE___TM_GMTOFF - Failed
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEZONE - Success
-- Performing Other Test GETTIMEOFDAY_GIVES_TZ - Success
-- Performing Other Test TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_TM_ZONE - Failed
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE - Failed
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_TIMEZONE - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STAT_ST_BLOCKS - Success
-- Looking for ioctl
-- Looking for ioctl - found
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STRUCT_VIDEOCONFIG - Failed
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_STRUCT_TEXT_INFO - Failed
-- Looking for _getvideoconfig
-- Looking for _getvideoconfig - not found
-- Looking for gettextinfo
-- Looking for gettextinfo - not found
-- Looking for _scrsize
-- Looking for _scrsize - not found
-- Looking for GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo
-- Looking for GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo - not found
-- Looking for TIOCGWINSZ
-- Looking for TIOCGWINSZ - found
-- Looking for TIOCGETD
-- Looking for TIOCGETD - found
-- Looking for getpwuid
-- Looking for getpwuid - found
-- Looking for alarm
-- Looking for alarm - found
-- Looking for fcntl
-- Looking for fcntl - found
-- Looking for flock
-- Looking for flock - found
-- Looking for fork
-- Looking for fork - found
-- Looking for frexpf
-- Looking for frexpf - found
-- Looking for frexpl
-- Looking for frexpl - found
-- Looking for gethostname
-- Looking for gethostname - found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - found
-- Looking for llround
-- Looking for llround - found
-- Looking for llroundf
-- Looking for llroundf - found
-- Looking for lround
-- Looking for lround - found
-- Looking for lroundf
-- Looking for lroundf - found
-- Looking for lstat
-- Looking for lstat - found
-- Looking for rand_r
-- Looking for rand_r - found
-- Looking for random
-- Looking for random - found
-- Looking for round
-- Looking for round - found
-- Looking for roundf
-- Looking for roundf - found
-- Looking for setsysinfo
-- Looking for setsysinfo - not found
-- Looking for signal
-- Looking for signal - found
-- Looking for longjmp
-- Looking for longjmp - found
-- Looking for setjmp
-- Looking for setjmp - found
-- Looking for siglongjmp
-- Looking for siglongjmp - found
-- Looking for sigsetjmp
-- Looking for sigsetjmp - found
-- Looking for sigprocmask
-- Looking for sigprocmask - found
-- Looking for snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf - found
-- Looking for srandom
-- Looking for srandom - found
-- Looking for strdup
-- Looking for strdup - found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for symlink
-- Looking for symlink - found
-- Looking for system
-- Looking for system - found
-- Looking for tmpfile
-- Looking for tmpfile - found
-- Looking for asprintf
-- Looking for asprintf - found
-- Looking for vasprintf
-- Looking for vasprintf - found
-- Looking for waitpid
-- Looking for waitpid - found
-- Looking for vsnprintf
-- Looking for vsnprintf - found
-- Performing Other Test VSNPRINTF_WORKS - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_C99_FUNC - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_C99_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER - Success
-- Performing Other Test SYSTEM_SCOPE_THREADS - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_SOCKLEN_T - Success
-- Performing CXX Test OLD_HEADER_FILENAME - Failed
-- Performing CXX Test H5_NO_NAMESPACE - Failed
-- Performing CXX Test H5_NO_STD - Failed
-- Performing CXX Test BOOL_NOTDEFINED - Failed
-- Performing CXX Test NO_STATIC_CAST - Failed
-- Performing CXX Test CXX_HAVE_OFFSETOF - Failed
-- Performing Other Test HAVE_INLINE - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE___INLINE__ - Success
-- Performing Other Test HAVE___INLINE - Success
-- Checking for appropriate format for 64 bit long:
-- Checking for appropriate format for 64 bit long: found "l"
-- Looking for difftime
-- Looking for difftime - found
-- Looking for clock_gettime
-- Looking for clock_gettime - found
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - not found
-- Looking for clock_gettime in posix4
-- Looking for clock_gettime in posix4 - not found
-- Checking IF your system converts long double to (unsigned) long values with special algorithm... no
-- Checking IF your system can convert (unsigned) long to long double values with special algorithm... no
-- Checking IF correctly converting long double to (unsigned) long long values... yes
-- Checking IF correctly converting (unsigned) long long to long double values... yes
-- Checking IF alignment restrictions are strictly enforced... yes
-- Found MPI_C: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpicc (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI_CXX: /Users/luca/lifev/lifev-env/libs/installs/openmpi-2.1.1_installRelease/bin/mpic++ (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI: TRUE (found version "3.1")  
-- Looking for MPI_Comm_c2f
-- Looking for MPI_Comm_c2f - not found
-- Looking for MPI_Info_c2f
-- Looking for MPI_Info_c2f - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

When I compile trilinos, however, I get compilation errors like 
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'H5Pset_fapl_mpio'; did you mean 'H5Pset_fapl_core'?`, which seem to indicate that hdf5 has not been configured correctly with parallel support. My question is: **how can I check if the configuration is ok (namely, if hdf5 has been really configured with parallel support)**? If this is the case, then the question is: **what could be the actual cause of the compilation problems I am having with trilinos**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I am posting my solution in the hope it will be useful to someone else, even if the mistake should have been easy to spot.

The problem was that trilinos was in fact including the header file of another installation of hdf5 which was not built with parallel support. In my case, uninstalling hdf5 with `brew uninstall hdf5` solved the issue.